# How to save post meta as an array in Gutenberg?

Tags: plugin-development, custom-field, block-editor

I am new to react and Gutenberg development and I am trying to add some fields in the Document sidebar.

While I have success saving the meta as single values I am struggling to find a way to save the fields as an array.

JS

```
import { __ } from '@wordpress/i18n';
import { compose } from '@wordpress/compose';
import { registerPlugin } from '@wordpress/plugins';
import { PluginDocumentSettingPanel } from '@wordpress/edit-post';
import { TextControl } from "@wordpress/components";
import { select, withSelect, withDispatch } from '@wordpress/data';
import { Fragment } from '@wordpress/element';

function TestControl( { newValue, updateMeta } ) {
    return (
        <Fragment>
            <TextControl
                label={ __( 'Field One', 'test' ) }
                value={ newValue.one }
                onChange={ ( value ) => updateMeta( value ) }
            />
            <TextControl
                label={ __( 'Field Two', 'test' ) }
                value={ newValue.two }
                onChange={ ( value ) => updateMeta( value ) }
            />
        </Fragment>
    );
}

const FieldsTestControl = compose( [
    withSelect( () => {
        return {
            newValue: select( 'core/editor' ).getEditedPostAttribute( 'meta' )._metakey,
        };
    } ),
    withDispatch( ( dispatch ) => ( {
        updateMeta( value ) {
            dispatch( 'core/editor' ).editPost(
                { meta: { _metakey:{
                    'one': value.one,
                    'two': value.two,
                } } }
            );
        },
    } ) ),
] )( TestControl );

const TestPanel = () => {
    return (
        <PluginDocumentSettingPanel
            name="test"
            title="Test"
            className="test"
        >
        <FieldsTestControl />
        </PluginDocumentSettingPanel>
    );
};

registerPlugin( 'test-panel', {
  render: TestPanel,
  icon: '',
} );
```

PHP

```
register_post_meta( 'post', '_metakey', [
    'type'          => 'object',
    'single'        => true,
    'auth_callback' => '__return_true',
    'show_in_rest'  => [
        'schema' => [
            'type'       => 'object',
            'properties' => [
                'one' => [
                    'type' => 'string',
                ],
                'two' => [
                    'type' => 'string',
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code is that in the `updateMeta()` function, the `value` is a string (which is whatever you typed or entered into the text field), so you can't do the `value.one` or `value.two`.

So try this instead which uses a new parameter for the function, namely `prop` which is the current property in the metadata that's being updated:

```js
updateMeta( value, prop ) { // the 'prop' is the current property to be updated
    let meta = select( 'core/editor' ).getEditedPostAttribute( 'meta' )._metakey;

    // Make sure all props are defined. (and merge with current metadata values)
    meta = {
        one: '',
        two: '',
        ...meta,
    };

    // Then update the current property.
    meta[ prop ] = value;

    dispatch( 'core/editor' ).editPost({ meta: { _metakey: meta } });
}
```

Then in the `TextControl`'s `onChange` attribute:

- Use `updateMeta( value, 'one' )` for the `Field One` field.
- Use `updateMeta( value, 'two' )` for the `Field Two` field.

And you don't have to use the exact same code I gave above, but it's a working (tested) example. Happy coding! :)

Comment: It worked great! Thanks so much!

Comment: PS: The spread syntax (`...`) is (simpler and) more commonly used in Gutenberg, so I revised the code.

Comment: I used the spread syntax and it's working fine. May I ask how we can format it in case the "two" value is an array?

Comment: You should post another question for that.. But you'd need to specify the exact schema (e.g. `'type' => 'object'`) for the property (e.g. the `two`) and make sure the property's properties are all set when saving the data.

Comment: You could also check this tutorial of mine for a complete guide: https://jeffreycarandang.com/how-to-enable-read-and-update-post-meta-in-the-wordpress-block-editor-gutenberg/.